# SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found when passing an array to a StoredProcedure

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

I'm trying to pass an Java String array to a PLSQL Stored-Procedure. After a lot of searching the internet I found a solution which does not work for me. 
First of all here is the package i declared with an PL/SQL Table called "CHAR_TABLE"

Package:

```
create or replace PACKAGE MYPACKAGE IS 
TYPE CHAR_TABLE IS TABLE OF CHAR(06) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE(
    p_strings      CHAR_TABLE
);
END MYPACKAGE;
```

And here is the body (also it isn't important):
    create or replace PACKAGE BODY MYPACKAGE IS

```
  PROCEDURE MYPROCEDURE(
    p_strings      CHAR_TABLE
) AS
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..p_strings.COUNT
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO myTable (s) VALUES (p_strings(i));
    END LOOP;
  END MYPROCEDURE;

END MYPACKAGE;
```

The Java-Code which If found on the internet ist the following:

```
OracleCallableStatement stmt = (OracleCallableStatement)oracleConnection.prepareCall("{call MYPACKAGE.MYPROCEDURE(?)}");



    String[] data = { "one", "two", "three" };
    Array array = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("MYPACKAGE.CHAR_TABLE", data);

    stmt.setArray(1, array);
    stmt.execute();

    conn.commit();
    conn.close();
```

But the problem is that I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01403: no data found

ORA-06512: at "BERNHARD.MYPACKAGE", line 9
ORA-06512: at line 1

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1017)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:655)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:566)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:210)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:53)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:938)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1075)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3923)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:5617)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1385)
```

Just for testing (to see if the call to the StoredProcedure works) I tried the following code:

```
OracleCallableStatement stmt = (OracleCallableStatement)oracleConnection.prepareCall("        DECLARE var BERNHARD.MYPACKAGE.CHAR_TABLE;\n" +
                "BEGIN\n" +
                "\n" +
                "var(1) := 'a';\n" +
                "var(2) := 'b';\n" +
                "MYPACKAGE.MYPROCEDURE(var);\n" +
                "END;");
stmt.execute();
```

And this works. But I need the first solution to bind a Java String Array to the input parameter of the Stored Procedure. How can I achieve that? Or what is my mistake?

Comment: Please disclose a version of your database and a version of your JDBC driver.

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.1.0</version> </dependency>

Comment: Can you for test only change CHAR(06) to varchar2(200) for sample and use substr on insert

Comment: Do you need to pass an associative array `TABLE OF CHAR(06) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;` ? Or a simple array (nested table or varray) would be sufficient ?

Comment: I've seen a similar error with `getArray()` when you don't have `grant execute` on the custom type. The driver seems to do some kind of metadata lookup on the type, but can't find the metadata because of permissions. If the exception contains a metadata query looking at all symbols, this could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing if a-array(associative array) comes from java. Its index starts from 0.
You can try change loop range or change the loop type at all. For a-array more appropriate is while loop.
Check example.

```
declare 
 type CHAR_TABLE IS TABLE OF CHAR(06) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
 p_strings  CHAR_TABLE;
 idx BINARY_INTEGER;
begin 
 p_strings(0) := 'aaaa';
 p_strings(1) := 'bbbb';
 p_strings(2) := 'cccc';
 -- 1-st option
 FOR i IN 0..p_strings.last  loop
  dbms_output.put_line(p_strings(i));
 end loop;
 -- 2-nd option
 idx := p_strings.first;
 while idx is not null
 loop
  dbms_output.put_line(p_strings(idx));
  idx := p_strings.next(idx);
 end loop;

end;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your guess was totaly right. This fixed my issue.